# Sorting lines in a file alphabetically using awk and/or sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with several hundred lines formatted as so:

```
#blah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/xyz(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#xblah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/hkf(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#ablah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abc/.*(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

I would like to create a script in awk/sed to alphabetize this file using the second argument in the third line of each group of text.  In the case of this file it's the "abc", "hkf" or "xyz" which could be anything - they're the redirects being created in this apache redirects file.

I figured that what I wanted to do was:

1. concatenate each group of three lines into one line with a delimiter between each line
2. sort the lines using sort -k3,3
3. then re-assemble the 3 line constructs with a separating blank line
4. write to file

My expected output would look like this:

```
#ablah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abc/.*(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#xblah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/hkf(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#blah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/xyz(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Does this make sense?  Is there a better way to do this?

p.s. my intent is to make the script portable so it can be used on several files of this structure.  When suggesting code to solve the problem, please spell it out as best possible for a rank newb like me to start to understand how to tackle this problem efficiently and be able to extend the end result.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is expected output file from above input?

Comment: anubhava, I've edited my OP, I think it makes more sense now.

Comment: sed does not suit well for sorting so awk will be your tool

Comment: If records are uniformly separated, e.g. with an empty line, this could be a one-liner in Perl.

Answer (score 6):

You can do the whole operation in Gnu Awk:

```
awk -f sort.awk input.txt
```

where `sort.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    RS=""
}
{
    match($0,/RewriteRule \^\/(.*)\(\|/,a)
    key[NR]=a[1] "\t" NR
    block[NR]=$0
}

END {
    asort(key)
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        split(key[i],a,"\t")
        print block[a[2]]
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
#ablah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abc/.*(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#xblah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/hkf(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

#blah
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/xyz(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: This awk script is pretty bullet proof, tried to break it a few ways - can't seem to so far.  Thank you very much for the solution.  I need to beat my head against it for a while in order to understand the logic - new at this.  Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea seemed a simple enough methodology. This seems to work for me on your test data. It does add extra blank lines though and I'm not focusing enough at the moment to sort that out.

```
awk '/^#/,/^$/ {printf "%s\0",$0} /^$/ {print ""} END {print ""}' 20250937.input | sort -t'\0' -k3,3 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

1. For all lines between /^#/ and /^$/ print the lines out with a null instead of a newline terminator.
2. When we see a blank line also print out a newline.
3. Ensure our output is terminated by a newline.
4. Sort on our fields.
5. Transform nulls back into newlines.

Comment: I've been able to edit the awk command to deal with 2 lines instead of 3, but I was wondering how I could modify the command above to be able to deal with both 2 and 3 lines in the same file?

Comment: That awk doesn't know anything about the amount of lines between the comment and the end of the block. The only part that cares about count is the sort. You need to be able to define what to sort on somewhere and if your sort target moves (or worse, isn't consistent between blocks) that is going to make things complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Some sed version:

```
sed -n '/^#/{N;h;n;H;x;s/\n/XnlX/g;x;s!.*\^/\([a-z]*\).*!\1!;G;s/\n/ /;p}' input \
         | sort |  sed 's/[^ ]* //;s/$/\n/;s/XnlX/\n/g'
```

*Produces:*

```
 #ablah 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/abc/.*(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

 #xblah 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/hkf(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]

 #blah 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.blah.com [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/xyz(|/)$ http://www.blah.com/404.html [R=301,L,NC]
```